# Internal Hard Disk Became Inaccessible After using it once in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I am a windows OS user. I installed Ubuntu 19 in my laptop and connected my hard disk (containing lots of important files) to the laptop. it worked fine.

But when i connected the hard disk back to my PC (running Windows 8.1 OS), it started giving message that "the disk is inaccessible".

Please give some suggestions what can i do to access my disk again in Windows PC. I already tried Disk manager in Linux.

Comment: Please clarify... are you talking about internal or external disks? USB?

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1315201/accessing-external-hdd-ext3-ubuntu-linux-files-from-windows-10

Comment: "I installed Ubuntu 19 in my laptop" - does this mean dual-booting? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: @heynnema i am talking about internal hard disk - with no boot record. it contains only project and media files.

Comment: @user535733 no it is not dual booted. my laptop has only ubuntu OS and i have another PC which is running on  Windows 8.1 OS. i can't access my hard disk drive in windows PC once I use it in my Ubuntu Laptop... thanks in advance

Comment: @user535733 sorry for not being clear. let me try once again. One PC with internal hard drive + Windows 8.1..... One Laptop with internal hard drive + Ubuntu Os. And I have another hard disk drive which i am using as external disk. In the past days i was a Windows Os user. my external drive worked well in Windows OS. but yesterday i installed Ubuntu on Laptop. And used external drive on Ubuntu to transfer some data...... here started the conflict.... after this when i connected the external hard drive to windows PC, it gave message that the drive is inaccessible. thanks in advance

Comment: PC's internal hard disk working fine....

Comment: On the Ubuntu machine, can you please show us a GParted screenshot of the external drive?

Comment: https://ibb.co/QFc8F49

Comment: https://imgur.com/JORXOYq  ......      https://imgur.com/sDG7HXM   ... https://imgur.com/KWmZECO

Comment: I hope the answer solves the problem but I doubt it. It looks like it was misused, not properly unmounted before disconnecting, and now tbe partitions and likely the partition table are corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, open a `cmd` (command) terminal with admin privs. With the drive(s) connected, type:

```
chkdsk /f e:
chkdsk /f f:
chkdsk /f g:
chkdsk /f H:
```

When using these drive(s) on Ubuntu, make sure to properly unmount the drive(s) before disconnecting them.

Comment: thank you @heynnema.i solved the  problem .

Comment: @prezrohit How did you solve the problem?

Comment: first of all, thanks @heynnema. i simply connected my hard disk to Ubuntu System and Formatted an empty disk with FAT file system (because it said that FAT fs can be used in any system), and it worked.